# How to inject Spring Bean in sesstion Listener

Tags: java, spring, session

I am trying to perform certain operation on database once session is destroyed and for that i have used session listener but the problem is that i need to have DAO object in session listener,
i have already tried injection,getting it from context file using `getBean()` but no success.(It's a simple spring 3,hibernate base 3 based application)

Any help is appreciated............

```
ApplicationContext ctx = 
            WebApplicationContextUtils.
                  getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());
```

Comment: I am not able to get DAO object in sessionlistener implementation

Comment: And where are you dao's defined? IN which application context? The one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` or the `DispatcherServlet`?

Comment: DAO are defined with @Repository annotation and loaded by ContextLoaderListener.

Comment: Then you should be able to access them in this way... So again what isn't working? Do you get a stack trace? null reference what? Pleas elaborate... Show some configuration, stack traces etc.

Comment: If i am trying to inject or getting the DAO object from getBean method i am getting null object and hence causing  nullpointer exception

Comment: Again post some code, configuration, post your actually listener. You cannot do dependency injection in a listener generally as that isn't a spring managed bean so things like `@Autowired` will simply not work. You will have to do a lookup.